# how to set bubble color in D3 based on ordinal values defined

Tags: d3.js, bubble-chart

I am working on a chart similar to http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nations/:

[image]

In this i want to define the colors and set it for each circles based on the region value read from json.

The code is:

```
 colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
       .range(["#7479BC","#7C2833","#E7AC37","BDE7AE","E17250","ECF809","FC6E61"]);//Ffb400


d3.json(data, function(d) {

   //code ...

var dot = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "dots")
    .selectAll(".dot")
      .data(interpolateData(2000))
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      //.style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(color(d)); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return  color(d.region); })
      .call(position)
      .sort(order);
```

})

My json file is

```
[
{

    "name":"Search&Navigator",
    "region":"IP&Science",
    "checkins":[[2000,100],[2001,200],[2002,300],[2003,275],[2004,222],[2005,280],[2006,281],[2007,400],[2008,55],[2009,300]],
    "teamsize":[[2000,10],[2001,7],[2002,7],[2003,12],[2004,5],[2005,3],[2006,10],[2007,12],[2008,12],[2009,10]],
    "Checkintimes":[[2000,40],[2001,50],[2002,60],[2003,50],[2004,40],[2005,30],[2006,30],[2007,35],[2008,30],[2009,30]]
},

{

    "name":"Cobalt",
    "region":"CORP",
    "checkins":[[2000,121],[2001,339],[2002,124],[2003,255],[2004,325],[2005,460],[2006,177],[2007,221],[2008,122],[2009,120]],
    "teamsize":[[2000,2],[2001,2],[2002,2],[2003,2],[2004,2],[2005,2],[2006,2],[2007,2],[2008,2],[2009,3]],
    "Checkintimes":[[2000,20],[2001,40],[2002,60],[2003,50],[2004,40],[2005,30],[2006,35],[2007,30],[2008,30],[2009,30]]
},

    "name":"Test",
    "region":"CORP",
    "checkins":[[2000,121],[2001,339],[2002,124],[2003,255],[2004,325],[2005,460],[2006,177],[2007,221],[2008,122],[2009,120]],
    "teamsize":[[2000,2],[2001,2],[2002,2],[2003,2],[2004,2],[2005,2],[2006,2],[2007,2],[2008,2],[2009,3]],
    "Checkintimes":[[2000,20],[2001,40],[2002,60],[2003,50],[2004,40],[2005,30],[2006,35],[2007,30],[2008,30],[2009,30]]
}
]
```

so based on the region value i would like to set the appropriate color. So All "CORP" should have the same color different from "IP&Science". currently it is setting all colors as black.

Comment: You're better off using a predefined colour scale for this, e.g. `d3.scale.category20()`.

Comment: You have an error in your JSON. You need a `{` before `"name":"Test",`

Comment: thanks christopher. I will look in to that.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because you are calling `color` and not `colorScale`?

Correcting the omitted curly bracket before the last object in your data I was able to style a circle in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6xza6/) with the data using the code below.

[image: Styled circle elements]

```
.append("circle")
    .style("fill", function (d) { return colorScale(d.region); })
    .attr('r', 5)
    .attr('cy', function (d, i) { return y(i); })
    .attr('cx', w / 2);
```